# 403 error on accessing nominatim on the virtual host

Tags: apache, ubuntu, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have installed nominatiom on virtual qemu ubuntu 16.04 server,
i can access apache's default page using http://127.0.0.1:8080 url in the host machine but i can not access any pages of nomination.

i test http://127.0.0.1:8080/nominatim/search.php either http://127.0.0.1:8080/nominatim/, but all of them response 403 forbidden message.

i created qemu virtual machine by this code:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -hda nominatim.img -enable-kvm -redir  tcp:8080::80 -redir tcp:2222::22
```

and this is apache's nominatim.conf file:

```
<Directory "/srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/website">
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AddType text/html   .php
  DirectoryIndex search.php
  Require all granted
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /nominatim /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/website
```

i used this tutorial for installing nominatim :
http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/Install-on-Ubuntu-16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't check the directories in the doc page. 
source files are in /srv/nominatim/**Nominatim-3.0.0**/build/website not /srv/nominatim/**Nominatim**/build/website!
so i edit correct path and it works!.